# Why won't my ng-include's load template when called in a ui-view?

Tags: angularjs

My `routes` file looks like:

```
.state('dashboard', {
  url: '/dashboard'
  views:
    appView:
      templateUrl: '/templates/main.html'
    dashboardView:
      templateUrl: '/templates/partialDashboard.html'
}).
```

`main.html` looks like:

```
<section class='main-page container'>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 lnHeaderArea">
      <ng-include src="'/templates/companyHeader.html'"></ng-include>
    </div>
    <div id="main-area" class="col-md-9">
      <div ui-view="dashboardView"></div>
      <ng-include src="'/templates/dashboardFooter.html'"></ng-include>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

and `partialDashboard.html` looks like:

```
<section ng-controller="DashboardController">
  <ng-include src="'/templates/dashboardInstitutionalDemand.html'"></ng-include>
  <ng-include src="'/templates/dashboardPriceVolume.html'"></ng-include>
  <ng-include src="'/templates/dashboardBlockExecutions.html'"></ng-include>
  <ng-include src="'/templates/dashboardAnalytics.html'"></ng-include>
</section>
```

But for some reason, those `ng-include`'d templates won't load. Any reason why?

Comment: may be this could be the reason: [The ng-view directive is a terminal directive at a 1000 priority. Angular will not run
any directives on the element at a lower priority, which is most directives (i.e., all other
directives on the <div ng-view></div> element are meaningless).]

Comment: Except I'm not using `ng-view`, I'm using `ui-view`, if that matters

Comment: I'm not sure but it should be the same

Comment: So then how do I get `ng-include` to function?

Comment: You need to use ui-router's views. I tried writing an explanation but it is too circluar

Comment: @itcouldevenbeaboat are you saying I need to use `ui-router views` INSTEAD of `ng-include`?

Comment: Do you get any errors ? Can you see any html files being loaded in the network inspector ?  Does your controller load ?

Comment: The controller loads, no errors and I see the proper HTML files in the network inspector

Comment: @Shamoon, does that mean all the html files in DashboardController ?

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer not entirely sure what you mean

Comment: @Shamoon I'm talking about the html files inside `<section ng-controller="DashboardController">`, are those showing up in the network tab, I want to determine first if your issue is network related or UI related.

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer they are not loading

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58804/discussion-between-willem-dhaeseleer-and-shamoon).

Comment: @Shamoon I have posted the answer. If that does not help you will have to create some plnkr so that we can help you further. But I am pretty sure your state definition is invalid as you have posted.

Comment: @bhantol, it's coffeescript

Comment: I see. Need a plunkr from OP. But as explained - ng-include works contrary to what OP is saying.

Comment: @Shamoon does your `partialDashboard.html` render anything besides the ng-includes?

Comment: @bhantol - nope just that

Comment: @Shamoon I'd say the only difference in my plunker and what you have is that mine is pure JS vs Coffeescript. Wondering if your problem gets resolved with this because it can't be a coffeescript problem. Also you may want to take a look at the library versions that I have and the ones you have just to rule out anything related to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ng-includes work fine inside the templateUrl.

Try [this Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DFn1hq?p=preview) or [Plnkr with state: views](http://plnkr.co/edit/QU5Iqm?p=preview) which demonstrates just that

Explanation is below

**Route using templateUrl**

This is in the route1 which has `templateUrl: route1.html`

```
 $stateProvider
        .state('route1', {
          url: "/route1",
          templateUrl: "route1.html"
        })
        .state('route1.list', {
          url: "/list",
          templateUrl: "route1.list.html",
          controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
          }
    })
```

or as per the state view like what you have

```
       .state('main', {
            url: '/main',
            views: {
                'route1': { 
                  templateUrl: "route1.html" 
                },
                'route2': { 
                  templateUrl: "route2.html" 
                },
            }
        })
```

**The template that has ng-include in it *-route1.html***
Notice myNgIncludeSample.html

```
  <h1>Route 1</h1>
   <hr/>
     <div ng-include="'myNgIncludeSample.html'">
      </div>
   <hr/>
   <a href="#/route1/list">Show List</a>
   <div ui-view></div>
```

I see that your .state('dashboard') looks different. You may want to fix your as below. Add those curly {} braces. UPDATED: The coffeescript syntax seems fine however my following pure JS code is working without any problem.

```
  .state('dashboard', {
      url: '/dashboard'
      views: {
        'appView': {
            templateUrl: '/templates/main.html'
         },
        'dashboardView': {
            templateUrl: '/templates/partialDashboard.html'
         }
   }).
```

Comment: Note that the OP is using coffee script

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer thanks for point it out. Issue remains as to "why" Shamoon is not having success. However my plnkr demonstrates that the concept works as to what OP is seeking

Comment: The plunker I created demonstrates ng-include in template. What other problem are you encountering.

Answer (score 0):

`ui-view` is a terminal directive and can't have ng-includes placed inside it. You need to define these templates inside your `$state` declaration by nesting:

```
.state('dashboard', {
  url: '/dashboard'
  views:
  appView:
    templateUrl: '/templates/main.html',
    views: {
      "myView":{
        templateUrl: '/templates/myView.html'
      }
    }
})
```

Comment: -1 OP ins't using `ng-view` but `ui-view` using ng-include in a ui-view is possible as shown here: http://plnkr.co/edit/AK9uYfpgTIHt9HUdHsjJ?p=preview

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer If you knew about Angular you'd know that that was clearly a typo since ng-view doesn't use `state` but `route` lol

Comment: I'm not claiming I'm an angular expert, but the fact that an `ng-include` works inside a `ui-view` still stands, so I don't think this answer is very helpful.

Comment: @OP Good luck to you sir

Comment: @itcouldevenbeaboat the issue is in a certain state, say `dashboard`, I may have 5 views. But in another state, say `account`, only one view. How can I account for that?

Comment: Hey @Shamoon. You can nest any number of states in a state using ui-router. Just nest them.